# Matrix to rotate Z axis to a given vector

Tags: matrix, rotation, rotational-matrices

For use in a 3D printing project, I want to generate a rotation matrix that rotates the z-axis into an arbitrary unit vector. I recognize that the problem is under-constrained: I have not said exactly what will happen to the X and Y axes, there is a free variable here concerning whether there is a twist about the z-axis. I DON'T CARE, I am rotating a cylinder. Or I might wish to say "in most direct way possible, no twist".  Either way works.

I got this far: supposing that [vx, vy, vz] is an arbitrary unit vector:

```
matrix = [[?, ?, vx],
          [?, ?, vy],
          [?, ?, vz]]
```

but how to fill in the blanks in the simplest possible manner?

Answer (score 0):

I will assume you have a set of coordinates [image] which are fixed, for example the edges of the frame of you 3d printer. Then your desired unitary axis given in those coordinates [image] has coordinates [image] and you want to bring any vector [image] into the new coordinate system [image] which is defined as [image] being aligned to [image].

I propose you define an appropriate rotation axis [image] and apply [Rodrigues' rotation formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rodrigues%27_rotation_formula). The choice of [image] could be an orthogonal vector to both [image] and the projection of [image] in the xy-plane, which is [image], and this vector can be determined by their cross product
[image]

Now you only need to find the rotation angle needed to apply [Rodrigues' rotation formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rodrigues%27_rotation_formula) which is trivially determined by a dot product:

[image]

For a more efficient implementation I would recommend employing the [matrix formulation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rodrigues%27_rotation_formula#Matrix_notation). Thus the new vector resulting from changing the coordinate system is

[image]

where [image] is the matrix encoding the transformation determined by Rodrigues' formula.